# rails 3: how to output the content of a array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

Im updating to rails 3 and experience the problem of writing the content of a array to a html view. If I just place the array like:

```
<%= array %>
```

It gets now outputed as:

> ["...","...","..."]

with rails 2 it was just the content which got printed...

Any Ideas?

Markus

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<%= array.join ' ' %>
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

You can try using [array#to_sentence](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence) method:

```
<%= array.to_sentence %>
```

Or just a join:

```
<%= array.join(", ") %>
```

Depends on how you want the output to look.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for debugging purposes, why not try:

```
<%= debug array %>
```

if you need to present the array in a specific way, you're better off iterating the array and presenting each element with a repeatable block or a partial.